# How to list the installed snaps on Ubuntu?

Tags: snap

How do I list the apps installed through `snap`?

```
lz@vm:$ snap help
The snap command lets you install, configure, refresh and remove snaps.
Snaps are packages that work across many different Linux distributions,
enabling secure delivery and operation of the latest apps and utilities.

Usage: snap <command> [<options>...]

Commonly used commands can be classified as follows:

         Basics: find, info, install, remove, list
        ...more: refresh, revert, switch, disable, enable, create-cohort
        History: changes, tasks, abort, watch
        Daemons: services, start, stop, restart, logs
    Permissions: connections, interface, connect, disconnect
  Configuration: get, set, unset, wait
    App Aliases: alias, aliases, unalias, prefer
        Account: login, logout, whoami
      Snapshots: saved, save, check-snapshot, restore, forget
         Device: model, reboot, recovery
      ... Other: warnings, okay, known, ack, version
    Development: download, pack, run, try
```

There's nothing that lists the snaps here

Comment: It's there in classified as "Basics". The `list`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open terminal and type `snap list`

[This reference](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-list-installed-packages-on-ubuntu) will assist you in listing all installed packages from various sources on ubuntu.

From [man page snap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/snap.1.html)

[image]